# Representation = BsonType.Int64 does not work properly with Datetime

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I am decorating one of my DateTime property in my class with Representation = BsonType.Int64 attribute so that it gets stored in the database with Int64 representation of a date.

When I used to store that property as a normal C# Datetime and did not set the value to anything then it would store DateTime.Min in the database. That is perfect because I was doing  reading from databse and doing Query.LT operation like following on it:

```
Query.LT("MyField", DateTime.Now));
```

And it used to return all the values fine.

Now that I started storing it as BsonType.Int64 and the equivalent of DateTime.Min in BsonType.Int64 is "0". my Query.LT("MyField", DateTime.Now)); fails on all the dates that are stored with DateTime.Min.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, during the query, the MongoDB driver doesn't know that you chose an alternate representation.

Hence, you need to query for an `Int64` explicitly:

```
Query.LT("MyField", DateTime.Now.Ticks));
```

This will work as expected (tested w/ MongoDB 2.1.1, C# driver 1.4.2.4500)

Comment: Yes.  This is how it has to be done at this time.  When you use the Query builder, we don't know that you are constructing a query for the class you put that attribute on.  In the next version, we'll have typed builders which will solve this problem.

Comment: Interesting. I guess that looks very natural in a linq context. What will the typed builders look like? Like `Query<MyType>.LT(...)`?

Comment: Query.Build<T>(q => q.LT(...).  However, because it is more natural to simply use linq, this is supported as well:  Query.Where<T>(t => t.DateTime < ...);